# C# Error CS0426 coming up when it shouldn't be VS2022

Tags: c#

I'm getting the error

> CS0426 "the type name 'GetRequest' does not exist in the type 'Request'

when I'm quite sure that it does. I don't understand what I possibly did wrong here. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
public class Request
{
    public static Request GetRequest()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In this class you can clearly see that `GetRequest` does infact exist within the type 'Request'. However when I try and use this method I get an error saying that it doesn't exist.

This line generates the error I have been getting:

```
Request req = new Request.GetRequest();
```

Comment: Typo: get rid of `new` from `= new Request.GetRequest(msg)`. Don't use `new` when calling a static method.

Comment: Amazing, that completely solved it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`new Request.GetRequest(msg);`
You're trying to create an instance of the type Request.GetRequest here, which in fact does not exist, what you probably wanted is `Request.GetRequest(msg)` calling the static method `GetRequest` in the Request class.